Possible Mold on plywood to use as subfloor
I picked up 8 sheets of second hand 3/4” plywood to use as attic flooring. I had them stored in my garage for a couple weeks. While cutting and taking them up to my attic today I noticed some white powdery substance on some sheets. I am assuming it is white mold. What am I to do? Can I clean it off? Should I rip it up and get rid of it? Some sheets are screwed down. If cleaning is an option I would lift up the sheets and clean both sides. Any advice? I am hoping I can clean it and forget about it. This will eventually be a sub floor when we finish the attic in a year or two. https://imgur.com/a/Zyq168c
https://imgur.com/a/zEMkTC1

I don't see any mold spots on the plywood in the pic.  Were the sheets wet in your garage?

Looks like a very, very small amount of mildew which will go away once the plywood dries out.

Yes not the best picture. Here is a close up of what I am talking about.https://imgur.com/a/zEMkTC1

They weren’t wet in my garage but it was humid in there. I am afraid they were wet before I bought them. Not sure if this should be a concern.

It doesn't look like mold to me, but I'm far from a mold expert (nor did I stay at a Holiday Inn Express last night).  If it's a concern to you, I would simply scrape it off, spray the area with a bleach solution, then let it dry.
Mold only occurs in wet conditions, so unless your attic is wet, that should be the end of it.
